# How can I prevent PHPickerViewController from showing content behind top bar items?

Tags: ios, swift, phpickerviewcontroller

In the image, the top bar is transparent which can be seen when scrolling the content up. I'd like for it to be opaque but since the controller shown here is the PHPickerViewController. I am not sure how to access the attributes I need to make it opaque.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I'm seeing the issue with your screenshot. But the truth is, could you post you code on presenting the image picker? That seems to me to be where the issue lies. PHPickerViewController requires iOS14 - and that means the default is a "card" style. (There are ways around this.)

Comment: It’s not transparent by default, are you utilizing an appearance API to make all navigation bars transparent? You could change it so you apply customizations only to specific instances of navigation bars rather than all of them.